# Force div's to expand to fill area

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to create a fullscreen layout for a TV monitor project in CSS and have the layout dynamically fill the entire screen, regardless of screen size.

My goal is to get a page looking like so:

```
----------------------------
|          header          |
----------------------------
| l|                    |r |
| e|                    |i |
| f|                    |g |
| t|      content       |h |
|  |                    |t |
|  |                    |  |
|  |                    |  |
----------------------------
|           footer         |
----------------------------
```

So far, I have been able to get most of the dynamic sizing done via percentages in CSS including the header and footer. However, I cannot get the left, content and right sections to completely fill the center area of the screen.

From my code below, the red div should not be visible as the center sections should always cover 100% of the red div. I have tried setting max-height/width to 100% as well as to inherit, which does not work.

I have spent multiple hours (prlly 10+) trying to get this layout to work and am getting no where. At this point, I am just changing CSS and moving code around to see if I can just happen to get it to work.

Why can I not get these sections to fill properly? Can someone point me in the right direction? Code below.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <header class="header">
        <strong>Header:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tortor. Praesent dictum, libero ut tempus dictum, neque eros elementum mauris, quis mollis arcu velit ac diam. Etiam neque. Quisque nec turpis. Aliquam arcu nulla, dictum et, lacinia a, mollis in, ante. Sed eu felis in elit tempor venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut ultricies porttitor purus. Proin non tellus at ligula fringilla tristique. Fusce vehicula quam. Curabitur vel tortor vitae pede imperdiet ultrices. Sed tortor.
    </header><!-- .header-->

    <aside class="left-sidebar">
        <strong>Left Sidebar:</strong> Integer velit. Vestibulum nisi nunc, accumsan ut, vehicula sit amet, porta a, mi. Nam nisl tellus, placerat eget, posuere eget, egestas eget, dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In elementum urna a eros. Integer iaculis. Maecenas vel elit.
    </aside><!-- .left-sidebar -->

    <aside class="right-sidebar">
        <strong>Right Sidebar:</strong> Integer velit. Vestibulum nisi nunc, accumsan ut, vehicula sit amet, porta a, mi. Nam nisl tellus, placerat eget, posuere eget, egestas eget, dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In elementum urna a eros. Integer iaculis. Maecenas vel elit.
    </aside><!-- .right-sidebar -->

    <div class="container">
        <main class="content">
            <strong>Content:</strong> Sed placerat accumsan ligula. Aliquam felis magna, congue quis, tempus eu, aliquam vitae, ante. Cras neque justo, ultrices at, rhoncus a, facilisis eget, nisl. Quisque vitae pede. Nam et augue. Sed a elit. Ut vel massa. Suspendisse nibh pede, ultrices vitae, ultrices nec, mollis non, nibh. In sit amet pede quis leo vulputate hendrerit. Cras laoreet leo et justo auctor condimentum. Integer id enim. Suspendisse egestas, dui ac egestas mollis, libero orci hendrerit lacus, et malesuada lorem neque ac libero. Morbi tempor pulvinar pede. Donec vel elit. Sed placerat accumsan ligula. Aliquam felis magna, congue quis, tempus eu, aliquam vitae, ante. Cras neque justo, ultrices at, rhoncus a, facilisis eget, nisl. 
        </main><!-- .content -->
    </div><!-- .container-->

</div><!-- .wrapper -->

<footer class="footer">
    <strong>Footer:</strong> Mus elit Morbi mus enim lacus at quis Nam eget morbi. Et semper urna urna non at cursus dolor vestibulum neque enim. Tellus interdum at laoreet laoreet lacinia lacinia sed Quisque justo quis. Hendrerit scelerisque lorem elit orci tempor tincidunt enim Phasellus dignissim tincidunt. Nunc vel et Sed nisl Vestibulum odio montes Aliquam volutpat pellentesque. Ut pede sagittis et quis nunc gravida porttitor ligula.
</footer><!-- .footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
/* Eric Meyer's CSS Reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/* End of Eric Meyer's CSS Reset */

html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
body {
    font: 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 80%;
    background-color: red;
}


/* Header
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.header {
    height: 20%;
    background: #FFE680;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}


/* Middle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.middle {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.middle:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: '';
}
.container {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    float: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: grey;
}
.content {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}


/* Left Sidebar
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.left-sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: #B5E3FF;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


/* Right Sidebar
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.right-sidebar {
    float: right;
    min-width: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    width: 25%;
    background: #FFACAA;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background: #BFF08E;
}
```

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle which may help: http://jsfiddle.net/AKw5d/

Comment: do you want to achieve this with css only or you can use JavaScript?

Comment: I have no limitations for this project. My end game is... just make this monitor work. :) The only reason I have not used any JS is I am not that familiar with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the trick to set columns to equal height — Chris Coiyer did an amazing write up on the possible techniques here: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Some few questions that you want to consider:

- Do you want to support legacy browsers, or just modern ones? If your answer is the latter, I would recommend the flex box fix.
- Are the background of a solid colour? If that's the case, you can always cheat using a background image, or absolutely positioned divs in the background.
- Is the order of columns in your markup adjustable? You have side (asideLeft-asideRight-mainContent) in your layout, which involves floating one of the aside element to the right. Do you mind using asideLeft-mainContent-asideRight layout instead?

I have looked into some solutions, and feels that the **one true layout** method may suit your needs the best. However, it involves using a very huge bottom padding, and a very huge negative bottom margin.

Markup is the same as you have provided, but I have altered your CSS by adding an override at the bottom of your original CSS.

```
.left-sidebar, .right-sidebar, .container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 9999px;
    margin-bottom: -9999px;
}
    .right-sidebar {
        float: right;
    }
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

There are a lot of redundant CSS properties that can be removed:

- If you have specified the height, you can omit declaration for min and max height.
- `padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px` can be converted into the shorthand, `padding: 10px`

You can go to this link (http://www.diffchecker.com/fqfq45io) to see the changes I have made to your CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/DGcQs/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">    </script><![endif]-->
<title></title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

<header class="header">
    <strong>Header:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tortor. Praesent dictum, libero ut tempus dictum, neque eros elementum mauris, quis mollis arcu velit ac diam. Etiam neque. Quisque nec turpis. Aliquam arcu nulla, dictum et, lacinia a, mollis in, ante. Sed eu felis in elit tempor venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut ultricies porttitor purus. Proin non tellus at ligula fringilla tristique. Fusce vehicula quam. Curabitur vel tortor vitae pede imperdiet ultrices. Sed tortor.
   </header><!-- .header-->

   <aside class="left-sidebar">
    <strong>Left Sidebar:</strong> Integer velit. Vestibulum nisi nunc, accumsan ut, vehicula sit amet, porta a, mi. Nam nisl tellus, placerat eget, posuere eget, egestas eget, dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In elementum urna a eros. Integer iaculis. Maecenas vel elit.
   </aside><!-- .left-sidebar -->

    <div class="container">
    <main class="content">
        <strong>Content:</strong> Sed placerat accumsan ligula. Aliquam felis magna, congue quis, tempus eu, aliquam vitae, ante. Cras neque justo, ultrices at, rhoncus a, facilisis eget, nisl. Quisque vitae pede. Nam et augue. Sed a elit. Ut vel massa. Suspendisse nibh pede, ultrices vitae, ultrices nec, mollis non, nibh. In sit amet pede quis leo vulputate hendrerit. Cras laoreet leo et justo auctor condimentum. Integer id enim. Suspendisse egestas, dui ac egestas mollis, libero orci hendrerit lacus, et malesuada lorem neque ac libero. Morbi tempor pulvinar pede. Donec vel elit. Sed placerat accumsan ligula. Aliquam felis magna, congue quis, tempus eu, aliquam vitae, ante. Cras neque justo, ultrices at, rhoncus a, facilisis eget, nisl. 
    </main><!-- .content -->
    </div><!-- .container-->

    <aside class="right-sidebar">
    <strong>Right Sidebar:</strong> Integer velit. Vestibulum nisi nunc, accumsan ut, vehicula sit amet, porta a, mi. Nam nisl tellus, placerat eget, posuere eget, egestas eget, dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. In elementum urna a eros. Integer iaculis. Maecenas vel elit.
   </aside><!-- .right-sidebar -->



  </div><!-- .wrapper -->

  <footer class="footer">
  <strong>Footer:</strong> Mus elit Morbi mus enim lacus at quis Nam eget morbi. Et semper urna urna non at cursus dolor vestibulum neque enim. Tellus interdum at laoreet laoreet lacinia lacinia sed Quisque justo quis. Hendrerit scelerisque lorem elit orci tempor tincidunt enim Phasellus dignissim tincidunt. Nunc vel et Sed nisl Vestibulum odio montes Aliquam volutpat pellentesque. Ut pede sagittis et quis nunc gravida porttitor ligula.
  </footer><!-- .footer -->

  </body>
  </html>
```

And the css is

```
 .middle {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: relative;
 }
.middle:after {
display: table;
clear: both;
content: '';
}
.container {
width: 50%;
height: auto;
float: inherit;
overflow: hidden;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background-color: grey;
float:left;
}
.content {
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
min-width: 100%;
height: auto;
min-height: 100%;
}


/* Left Sidebar
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.left-sidebar {
float: left;
width: 25%;
min-height: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
position: relative;
background: #B5E3FF;
/* padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;*/
overflow: hidden;
}


/* Right Sidebar
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.right-sidebar {
float: right;
width: 25%;
background: #FFACAA;
min-height: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
/*padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;*/
overflow: hidden;
}


/* Footer
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.footer {
width: 100%;
height: 20%;
background: #BFF08E;
float:left;
}
```